# Change column type using laravel migration using Doctrine DBAL gives error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, laravel-5, migration

I use Laravel 5.2, Php7, Apache, Windows

my **migration file** is "2016_03_30_095234_alter_date_update_news_table.php"

```
class AddSlugUpdateNewsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     * php artisan make:migration add_slug_update_news_table
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('slug')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dateTime('slug')->change();
        });
    }
}
```

---

But after run migrate,

`$\> php artisan migrate`

gives me **this error**!

> [RuntimeException]   Changing columns for table "news" requires
>       Doctrine DBAL; install "doctrine/dbal".

**what do i do?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Warning:** Use this method only when you are sure to loose all the values of that column and can have fresh values in it.
>
> > ***But if you want to preserve then this is not the right solution for you.***

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 * php artisan make:migration alter_date_update_news_table
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('date');
    });
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->date('date')->after('image');
    });        
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('date');
    });
    Schema::table('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dateTime('date')->after('image');
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

according to laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns). You must install **doctrine/dbal** first if you are using `->change()` function.

Type `composer require doctrine/dbal` in your terminal

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you're missing a dependency.

Install it with composer:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```